# Selenium (Java) message "Unable to locate element" but element and XPath exist

Tags: java, selenium, exception, xpath, webdriver

I am new to Selenium WebDriver, using NetBeans Java and Firebug for Firefox to get XPath.

The problem is even though some elements are visible and clickable in the browser, and [Firebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) finds the XPath expression, I still get an error "Unable to locate element". The problem is, the element is not in a frame (there aren’t any frames), not in another window, it's visible and clickable and it has a clear XPath expression.

I used Wait and Thread.sleep, but it didn't help.
Also, I tried all solutions I could find on Stack Overflow similar to this matter.

The element is inside of the table which has some "div" elements inside. This is the XPath expression:

```
.//*[@id='NavigationRadPanelBar_i2_i0_trvStandardView']/ul/li[3]/div/span[3]
```

It seems that the panel is a problem, because it can not locate the panel too. I tried another element inside the same panel which has a title and text with this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Technical Attributes')]")).click();
```

But still I got same message. Similar for all elements inside this panel and panel itself. It seems whatever I tried, it's unable to locate. Everything outside of this panel is working fine with drivers.

The page has a left panel where these elements are located. Some of them are nodes that can be expanded, and some are just links, but nothing can be located.

What can be the cause of element that is obviously existing and visible, but still cannot be located by WebDriver?

I tried to locate the main panel:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='NavigationRadPane']")).click();
```

but still the same exception.

This is part of the HTML content (it's very long):

```
<div id="RAD_SLIDING_PANE_CONTENT_navigatiionRadSlidingPane" class="rspSlideContent" style="overflow: hidden; width: 200px; height: 579px;">
  <div id="NavigationRadPanelBarPanel" style="display: block;">
    <div id="NavigationRadPanelBar" class="RadPanelBar RadPanelBar_Office2007" postback="false" style="background-color:GhostWhite;height:100%;width:100%;">
      <ul class="rpRootGroup">
        <li class="rpItem rpFirst">
          <li class="rpItem">
            <li class="rpItem rpLast">
              <a class="rpLink rpExpandable rpExpanded" href="#">
                <div class="rpSlide" style="display:block;">
                  <ul class="rpGroup rpLevel1 111460" style="display: block; height: 274.731px; width: 100%;">
                    <li class="rpItem rpFirst rpLast">
                      <div class="rpTemplate">
                        <div id="NavigationRadPanelBar_i2_i0_trvStandardView" class="RadTreeView RadTreeView_Office2007">
                          <ul class="rtUL rtLines">
                            <li class="rtLI rtFirst">
                              <li class="rtLI">
                                <li class="rtLI">
                                  <div class="rtMid">
                                    <span class="rtSp" />
                                    <span class="rtPlus rtPlusHover" />
                                    <img class="rtImg" src="..." alt="Technical Attributes" />
                                    <span class="rtIn" title="Technical Attributes">Technical Attributes</span>
                                  </div>
                                  <ul class="rtUL" style="display:none;">
                                </li>
                                <li class="rtLI rtLast">
```

Comment: Thanks, fo providing this info. It will be great if you can share the HTML for the left panel elements.

Comment: I pasted part of html. Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you sure it exists when the page first loads? It's possible if it's part of a panel that something must be clicked/expanded to create that element.

Comment: It's possible. Panel has a "undock" option (pin) but the pin is currently put so it opens immediately. Could it be the cause, even if the panel is pinned up so that it's opened?

Comment: Could it be to the fact that the whole panel is pinned and when unpinned it needs to be expanded by clicking on it?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
```

This way, the driver will switch to the panel you have clicked. Then you can perform the rest of the operations you want in the panel.

Comment: Problem is that panel is also "unable to locate". I am not sure how to use this, I tried, but it still throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to your question:

The error says it all, *Unable to locate element*, because the XPath expression seems incorrect to me.

If you want to click on the element with *title* set to *Technical Attributes* you can consider to try with the following XPath expressions:

```
//div[@id='NavigationRadPanelBar_i2_i0_trvStandardView']/ul/li/li/li/div/span[@class='rtIn']
```

or

```
//div[@id='NavigationRadPanelBar_i2_i0_trvStandardView']/ul/li/li/li/div/span[@title='Technical Attributes']
```

Comment: I am sorry, just tried it, didn't work. Same error. This path seems correct so it has to be some other cause, not path. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @BiljanaM. What is the error you see now? Can you update the error stack trace in the Question area please?

Comment: It's same:Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //div[@id='NavigationRadPanelBar_i2_i0_trvStandardView']/ul/li/li/li/div/span[@title='Technical Attributes']

Comment: @BiljanaM. As you are getting `NoSuchElementException` on my suggested xpath and also using `xpath` as `.//*[@id='NavigationRadPane']` I am sure either the element is within an `iFrame` or you need to induce `ExplicitWait`. Thanks

Comment: @BiljanaM. If the URL is a public URL consider sharing it so I can help you out. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, it\s not public URL.